# Valid Answer Deleted and changed to Comment

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, deleted-answers, convert-to-comment

My question is not to challenge but to understand if my "understanding" is correct.

Today one of my post was removed and converted into a link.

Link: [Build a Comma Delimited String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934184/build-a-string-in-excel-vba/8934247#8934247)

I feel it was a valid answer and not merely a link. I have seen many answers which have been accepted which are just bare links and they continue to exists + upvoted.

This was my answer.

[image]

and this is the comment.

[image]

The FAQ says

> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed.
>   This includes answers that are …
>
> commentary on the question or other answers
>
> asking another, different question
>
> “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
>
> exact duplicates of other answers
>
> **barely more than a link to an external site**
>
> not even a partial answer to the actual question

**My Question**: Is my understanding incorrect?

**EDIT**

I have ended up being more confused now. This [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)(An accepted Answer) says

> You should provide context to all your links, otherwise the OP will have no idea what they are clicking into.

Haven't I already done that?

So now I go back and edit the post. I quote nearly the same things from the link so that if that link ever dies, my post remain good enough and also want to ensure that I do not plagiarize the contents of that post... I even added a Tag line `Quote From the link in case the link ever dies` What else am I supposed to do?

So could anyone please explain what is the best practice in this case?

**UPDATE**

The answer has been undeleted.

Comment: You bolded the correct line.

Comment: Thanks Robert. But it is not just a bare link?

Comment: @SiddharthRout It pretty much is just a link--you just say "look here" and give the link

Comment: Have a look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259

Comment: So it would be right if I undelete the post and add more relevant info?

Comment: You can edit it, but a moderator deleted it; you'll have to flag for moderator attention to get it undeleted.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: How would I know if a moderator deleted it or not?

Comment: casperOne deleted it.  He has a diamond next to his name.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Sorry it didn't show the name on the post... In fact it doesn't show anything. I will edit it and then flag it. thanks

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Strange. I double checked it and cannot see who deleted the post...

Comment: `I have seen many answers which have been accepted which are just bare links and they continue to exists + upvoted.` Please tell me which ones, I will happily flag those!

Comment: @JimmyPena: That would be retaliation, if I did and that's not correct. I am sure you will come across many :)

Comment: Sorry no, that would be helping to clean up the site. I may have a couple of link-only answers out there, if I come across them myself I will flag/delete them, and fully expect anyone else who comes across them to do the same.

Comment: @JimmyPena: Yes but when I see them I will flag it. I am not going to actively search for it :)

Comment: @JimmyPena If you come across your own, why not edit them and incorporate the gist of the linked contents?

Comment: @Siddharth OK ...

Comment: @DanielFischer You're right, that's a better idea.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: if you post it as an answer. I will accept it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: For some reason, it only shows you who deleted it when there's not some odd only-you-can-see-this-note text there. That note doesn't show for other users, so they can see who deleted it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I improved the post as you suggested and flagged it but it was ignored? Am I missing something?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Give them some time to review the flag. (Or was it declined?) There are a lot of flags around, and undeleting an answer probably isn't top priority.

Comment: @DanielFischer: The flag was already actioned 30 mins ago as helpful but the post was not undeleted.

Comment: You copied nearly the entire contents of a blog post. That's not a good thing.

Comment: Ahem, that's indeed strange. I'd expect either decline or action on that type of flag.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter: Yes I did. And i did also metion in the post `Quote From the link in case the link ever dies` I cannot edit the actual contents as the credit goes to Chip.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Need your opinion again. I am actually getting confused now as to how this works. I came across this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917128/phonegap-vs-rhomobile/8922789#8922789 and I flagged it since it is a bare link and it was declined. What am I missing?

Comment: Well, we're not going to delete answers that have five upvotes and were the accepted answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Thanks but isn't it going against the FAQ?

Comment: The rules are never going to be enforced 100% of the time.  It's never that black and white.  If it were, we wouldn't need moderators.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Somehow I am not convinced. but since it is directly coming from you (a moderator) I guess I will just shut up and move on... Thanks again.

Comment: In the example you provided, I don't see any way for the answer poster to summarize the link (it's a comparison matrix; here it is), and the question, though borderline off-topic, didn't generate extended discussion, so c'est la vie.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: C'est la vie. Very true...